# Hide multi WooCommerce shipping methods based on product attributes not used for variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, shipping-method

On my WooCommerce website, each product has four attributes (Size, Colour, Season and Brand). The attributes Size and Colour are used for variations, while Season and Brand are not used for variations.

I set up 3 shipping methods: Free Shipping (ID 17) with no minimum order, Free Shipping (ID 8) with a minimum order of €100, and finally Paid Shipping (ID 1) of €9.99.

I would like to have Free Shipping (ID 17) with a minimum order of €100 and Paid Shipping (ID 1) of €9.99 when purchasing a product from the S24 season, whereas if you purchase a product from the F23 season, Free Shipping (ID 8) with a minimum order of €100 and Paid Shipping (ID 1) of €9.99 must be activated. In the last case, where you buy at least one product from the S24 season and at least one product from the F23 season, only the free shipping (ID 17) without a minimum order must be activated .

Here is the starting code, but it only works with the attributes used for variations:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_product_attribute', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_product_attribute( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Product Attribute taxonomy (start always with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_season'; // Example for "Season"

    // Array of Shipping method rate ID and term(s) slug(s) pairs
    $data_array = array(
        'free_shipping:8'     => array('s24'),
        'free_shipping:17'    => array('f23'),
        'flat_rate:1'         => array('f23'),
    );

    // Loop through items in the current shipping package
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ){
        // Get the parent variable product if it's a product variation
        $product = $item['variation_id'] > 0 ? wc_get_product($item['product_id']) : $item['data'];
            
        // Loop through our data array
        foreach( $data_array as $rate_id => $term_slugs ) {
            // loop through product attributes
            foreach($product->get_attributes() as $attribute ) {
                if( $attribute->get_taxonomy() === $taxonomy && isset($rates[$rate_id]) 
                && count( array_intersect($attribute->get_slugs(), $term_slugs) ) > 0 ) {
                    unset($rates[$rate_id]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will handle all your required cases:

- "S24" term found: Free Shipping (ID 17 with min subtotal of €100) and Paid Shipping activated,
- "F23" term found: Free Shipping (ID 8 with min subtotal of €100) and Paid Shipping activated,
- "S24" and "F23" terms found: Free Shipping (ID 17 with min subtotal of €100) activated.

**Important:** You will need to **remove** from both Free shipping methods settings, the minimum order amount restriction, as it is handled in the code.

Try the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_product_attribute', 90000, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_product_attribute( $rates, $package ) {
    $free_min_subtotal = 100; // Set the minimal amount for free shipping
    $taxonomy = 'pa_season'; // Product Attribute taxonomy (start always with "pa_")
    $has_s24 = $has_f23 = false; // Initializing

    $cart_subtotal = $package['cart_subtotal']; // Or use $package['contents_cost'] to exclude taxes

    // Loop through items in the current shipping package
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ){
        // Get the parent variable product if it's a product variation
        $product = $item['variation_id'] > 0 ? wc_get_product($item['product_id']) : $item['data'];
        // Loop through product attributes
        foreach($product->get_attributes() as $attribute ) {
            // Check for "Season" PA
            if( $attribute->get_taxonomy() === $taxonomy ) {
                $term_slugs = $attribute->get_slugs();
                
                if ( in_array( 's24', $attribute->get_slugs() ) ) {
                    $has_s24 = true;
                } elseif ( in_array( 'f23', $attribute->get_slugs() ) ) {
                    $has_f23 = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Case 1 (term "s24" found)
    if ( isset($rates['free_shipping:17']) && isset($rates['flat_rate:1']) && $has_s24 && ! $has_f23 ) {
        if ( isset($rates['free_shipping:8']) ) {
            unset($rates['free_shipping:8']); // remove Free Shipping 8
        }
        // Handle minimum cart amount for free shipping
        if ( isset($rates['free_shipping:17']) && floatval($cart_subtotal) < $free_min_subtotal ) {
            unset($rates['free_shipping:17']); // remove Free Shipping 17 (required subtotal is lower)
        }
    } 
    // Case 2 (term "f23" found)
    elseif ( isset($rates['free_shipping:8']) && isset($rates['flat_rate:1']) && $has_f23 && ! $has_s24 ) {
        if ( isset($rates['free_shipping:17']) ) {
            unset($rates['free_shipping:17']); // remove Free Shipping 17
        }
        // Handle minimum cart amount for free shipping
        if ( isset($rates['free_shipping:8']) && floatval($cart_subtotal) < $free_min_subtotal ) {
            unset($rates['free_shipping:8']); // remove Free Shipping 8 (required subtotal is lower)
        }
    } 
    // Case 3 (terms "s24" and "f23" found)
    elseif ( isset($rates['free_shipping:17']) && $has_s24 && $has_f23 ) {
        if ( isset($rates['free_shipping:8']) ) {
            unset($rates['free_shipping:8']); // remove Free Shipping 8 
        }
        if ( isset($rates['flat_rate:1']) ) {
            unset($rates['flat_rate:1']); // remove Flat rate 1 
        }
    } 
    // Fallback: For security regarding free shipping and minimal required subtotal
    elseif ( floatval($cart_subtotal) < $free_min_subtotal ) {
        if ( isset($rates['free_shipping:8']) ) {
            unset($rates['free_shipping:8']); // remove Free Shipping 8 
        }
        if ( isset($rates['free_shipping:17']) ) {
            unset($rates['free_shipping:17']); // remove Free Shipping 17
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Note: Don't forget to empty the cart, to refresh shipping cached data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code works correctly if I deactivate the WooCommerce Local Pickup Plus plugin. With the plugin active, it fails to calculate the cart subtotal properly. Here is the site on which I am applying the code. [link](https://duepassicalzature.it/) How can I solve it?

Comment: here is a screenshot of the error: https://paste.pics/1e06de3116c4f1c966b0143b76c3b9f4

Comment: @LucaMoschetta My answer here answers your initial question and works… The fact that you are using a non-official 3rd party plugin that is making trouble is something else… Sometimes you need to choose between a plugin and custom coding… Maybe what you can try is to increase the hook priority (see my updated code), but I am not sure that it will solve the issue. Now, as you get enough reputation if you like or want, you could upvote your accepted answer *(to upvote, click the large up arrow to the left of the answer)*.